# Specify class with forwardable

Tags: ruby, delegation

I'm trying to use ruby's [`forwardable` module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) to make some variables in one class accessible to another class. However I am having some trouble doing this.

It seems that I'm able to 'forward' some variables within the `self` (first bit of code) but I'm unable to forward some variable within a class (second bit of code)

The following works:

```
require 'forwardable'
module ModuleName
  #
  class << self
    attr_accessor :config
    def run
      @config = {hey: 'hi', jay: 'ji'}
      puts "1) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end

  #
  class Start
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators ModuleName, :config
    def run
      puts "2) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end
end


ModuleName.run
(ModuleName::Start.new).run

#=> 1) Config = {:hey=>"hi", :jay=>"ji"}
#=> 2) Config = {:hey=>"hi", :jay=>"ji"}
```

BUT this doesn't

```
require 'forwardable'
module ModuleName
  #
  class Data
    attr_accessor :config
    def run
      @config = {hey: 'hi', jay: 'ji'}
      puts "1) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end

  #
  class Start
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators ModuleName::Data, :config
    def run
      puts "2) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end
end


(ModuleName::Data.new).run
(ModuleName::Start.new).run

#=> 1) Config = {:hey=>"hi", :jay=>"ji"}
#=> /Users/ismailm/Desktop/ex.rb:17:in `run': undefined method `config' for ModuleName::Data:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Can you help in fixing this part of the code...

Comment: Should'nt it be `def_delegators ModuleName::Data, :config` (as your class is not just self now)

Comment: @Tensibai yes You're right, that is what I tried (I copied it wrong)... but it didn't work. See updated code above

Comment: You cannot delegate `:run` to `ModuleName::Data`, because `ModuleName::Data.run` does not exist. Are you looking to define `ModuleName::Data.run` or delegate the call to an instance of `ModuleName::Data`? Usually with delegation, you expect to have something dynamic to delegate to - delegating direct to a singleton method is unusual (since you already have other mechanisms for making that static link in code)

Comment: @NeilSlater I'm not too sure what you mean, I'm trying to what is done in the first bit of code - i.e. making the instance variable `config` accessible to the second class...

Comment: OK, I am writing an answer - but in short your instance variable is associated with an instance, but you provide no instance for the delegation to call. It won't construct one for you by naming the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when you delegate between two classes, one object contains an *instance* of the other. The fact that you call `(ModuleName::Data.new).run` implies to me that is what you are trying to do, but are somehow missing the fact that you need an instance of the contained class to be stored somewhere in order to receive the call to `:config`

This variation of your second piece of code is closer to what I would expect to see in a delegation scenario:

```
require 'forwardable'
module ModuleName
  #
  class Data
    attr_accessor :config

    def initialize
      @config = {hey: 'hi', jay: 'ji'}
    end

    def run
      puts "1) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end

  #
  class Start
    extend Forwardable

    def initialize data_obj = Data.new()
      @data = data_obj
    end

    def_delegators :@data, :config

    def run
      puts "2) Config = #{config}"
    end
  end
end


(ModuleName::Data.new).run
(ModuleName::Start.new).run
```

I changed the constructor to `ModuleName::Start` in order to show a common pattern, not used here. Namely, you often pass in the wrapped object, or even more commonly the params that allow you to construct a new one and assign it to the instance variable that you wish to delegate to.

A minor related change: In your original code, the value of `@config` was only set via calling `:run`, so delegating direct to `:config` won't read the value you expect in the test. It worked in the first version because `@config` was set in the first call to `run` on the module, and then read globally as a singleton method on the second delegated call. I have worked around that here by setting it in `Data`s constructor, but of course anything that sets the value of `@config` on the instance you are delegating to would work.